# Pillow masked extraction without pixel subscripting?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have one jpeg, call it template.jpg that is a blank ballot. I need to compare this with thousands of scanned ballots, imagexxxx.jpg to see any marks that the user put on the form, even those extraneous to the purpose.

One way to do this would be a nested loop across all pixels like this:

```
tmpl = Image.open('template.jpg')
tmpl = tmpl.convert(mode='1', dither=0) 
im = Image.open('imagexxxx.jpg')
pxtmpl = tmpl.load()
pxim = im.load()
for i in range(tmpl.size[0]):
    for j in range (tmpl.size[1]):
        if pxtmpl[i,j] == 0:
            pxim[i,j] = (255,255,255)
im.show()
```

However pixel access is slow.

Needless to say I am willing to spend almost any amount of CPU creating the template file in its optimal format in order to minimize the per-ballot time.

I have been hoping to find some channel-op or clever use of the .point method but haven't found one that worked?

Any suggestions for how to get this done with minimal per-ballot processing time?

(For this discussion I am ignoring the issue of misregistration of ballots vs the template in scanning.)